# For each loops in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, foreach

Here is the code:

```
void translateOutline(vector<Point>& outline, Point center)
{
    for (auto & point : outline){
        point = point + center;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a for each loop in C++ opencv, where for each point in the point vector, I try to add the center to the point.

But I'm getting a operator mismatch error. I can't find any documentation on how exactly i can add points using a for each loop. But does this look correct?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, did you include `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>` ?

Comment: Yess. I'm not sure why I get I get the mismatched type errors.

Comment: Are you using a different namespace? Possibly you are including a namespace that also has the Point class, or have written you own Point class which is different from the `cv::Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `auto` to `Point`, while you want to change a `Point`, which is the content of the vector:

```
for (Point& point : outline){
```